How to Properly Configure Cookies and CORS for Spring Boot Backend and React Frontend on Different Subdomains?
I am currently working on a project where the backend is implemented using Spring Boot & Spring Security, and the frontend is built with React. Both the backend and frontend are hosted on render.com. My domain structure is as follows:
Frontend: example.com
Backend: api.example.com
I am facing issues with setting cookies correctly from the backend to the frontend. Specifically, I'm encountering the following error: Some cookies are misusing the recommended “SameSite“ attribute
CORS Configuration:
@Override
public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
    registry.addMapping("/**")
            .allowedMethods("*")
            .allowedHeaders("*")
            .allowedOrigins("https://example.com")
            .allowCredentials(true)
            .maxAge(-1);
}

Cookie Configuration:
ResponseCookie cookie = ResponseCookie.from(cookieName, value)
        .httpOnly(true)
        .secure(true)
        .maxAge(expiration)
        .path("/")
        .build();


Despite this setup, I am unable to get the cookies to be set correctly.
What am I missing in my configuration to properly set cookies and handle CORS between example.com and api.example.com?
I tried different configurations, but they won't solve the issue.
